# NfcV - how to getHistoricalBytes, like in NfcA?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

In `NfcA` standard there is an `android.nfc.tech.IsoDep` class. It has a method called: `getHistoricalBytes()`. How to get this functionality in `NfcV` standard? `IsoDep` class doesn't work here. Any ideas? Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NfcV (ISO15693) technology doesn't has anything like HistoricalBytes. HistoricalBytes only exist in the NfcA (ISO14443-A) standard.

The only static thing you can read from a NfcV Tag is the UID and the DSF-ID (data structure format identifier, often not used). You get it by casting your tag object to an NfcV object and then call getDsfID()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcV.html

Comment: Thanks, I knew about UID and DSF-ID but needed to ensure that there's nothing I'm missing - now I'm sure there's no way to read these bytes.